# Pass NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN environment variable via docker run command

Tags: docker, neptune

Using the `docker run` command, I'm trying to pass my NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN to my container.

My understanding is that I should use the `-e` flag as follows: `-e ENV_VAR='env_var_value'` and that might work.
I wish, however, to use the value existing in the already-running session, as follows:

```
docker run -e NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN=$(NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN) <my_image>
```

However, after doing so, NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN is set to empty when checking the value inside the container.
My question is whether I'm doing something wrong or if this is not possible and I must provide an explicit Neptune API token as a string.

Answer (score 1):

`$(NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN)` is the syntax for running a command and grabbing the output. Use `$NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you elaborate on the difference, when to use which?

Comment: As an example, take `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` which removes all stopped containers. It runs the command `docker ps -aq` and puts the output into the `docker rm` command. `echo $PATH` on the other hand outputs the value of the environment variable `PATH`. So they're quite different.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up and pass NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN as a:

1. [Docker run command options environment variable](https://docs.neptune.ai/how-to-guides/automation-pipelines/how-to-use-neptune-with-docker#step-3-build-and-run-docker-container-passing-api-token)

Example: `docker run -e NEPTUNE_API_TOKEN="<YOUR_API_TOKEN>" <image-name>`

2. [Dockerfile environment variable](https://docs.neptune.ai/how-to-guides/automation-pipelines/how-to-use-neptune-with-docker#step-3-build-and-run-docker-container-passing-api-token)
3. [Docker secret](https://docs.neptune.ai/how-to-guides/automation-pipelines/how-to-use-neptune-with-docker#step-3-build-and-run-docker-container-passing-api-token)

Neptune will work with any of the methods described above.

For your case, I believe using method 2 and 3 will work best as you will set the API token only once and all containers can reuse it. Additionally, they are more secure methods.

You can read this guide on how to use Neptune with Docker I created last year.

Docs: https://docs.neptune.ai/how-to-guides/automation-pipelines/how-to-use-neptune-with-docker